# Pass list of values to SciPy fsolve argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I have the following function:

```
def equation1(xy, d=7.62, G=8.2728, rhop=7.51, ut=399):
    ep, uc = xy     # define variables
    g = 981         # acceleration due to gravity, cm/s^2

    f1 = 2*g*d*((ep**-4.7) - 1) - 0.01*(uc/ep - ut)**2
    f2 = G - (uc/ep - ut)*rhop*(1 - ep)
    return f1, f2
```

where I solve for `ep` and `uc` by using `fsolve` in SciPy:

```
ep1, uc1 = fsolve(equation1, [1, 500])
```

Instead of defining a single value for `G`, I would to like solve for `ep` and `uc` for a range `G` values such as `G = [8, 10, 12]`. When I pass a list of values for G, I get an error about setting an array element with a sequence.

Is it possible to use `fsolve` where one of the arguments is a list or array of values?

Comment: Do you want to solver `ep,uc` for each value of `G`? In that case you'll have to loop over those values and call `fsolve` for each case.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Yes, I want to solve for `ep, uc` for each value of `G`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can keep `G` as a parameter to `equation1` and pass it via `fsolve` (using its `args` parameter) as:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def equation1(xy, G, d=7.62, rhop=7.51, ut=399):
    ep, uc = xy     # define variables
    g = 981         # acceleration due to gravity, cm/s^2

    f1 = 2*g*d*((ep**-4.7) - 1) - 0.01*(uc/ep - ut)**2
    f2 = G - (uc/ep - ut)*rhop*(1 - ep)
    return f1, f2


for G in [8, 10, 12]:
    ep1, uc1 = fsolve(equation1, [1, 500], (G, ))
    print(G, ep1, uc1)
```

this gives on my machine:

```
8 0.994582431487 592.401268397
10 0.993718674117 607.148953105
12 0.992912345764 620.018209488
```

Comment: Is it required to pass `G` within a tuple?  Since the for-loop passes one value at each iteration, it seems like the tuple is not needed for a single argument.

Comment: @wigging passing just `G` also works, I used the tuple just to show where it would be necessary to insert possible additional arguments...

Comment: Thank you for the help, your answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If I run your function with:

```
In [83]: ep1, uc1 = fsolve(equation1, [1, 500],args=(7.62, [8,10,12]))
...
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

But look at the call stack.  It's long, but this line stands out

```
res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
```

It's making a test call to your function.

So for example:

```
In [121]: x0=np.array([1,500])
In [122]: numinputs=2
In [123]: args = (1,8)     # scalar G
In [124]: np.atleast_1d(equation1(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
Out[124]: array([-102.01,    8.  ])

In [125]: args = (1,[8,10])    # list G
In [126]: np.atleast_1d(equation1(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
....
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Looking specifically at what your function produces:

```
In [127]: equation1(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args))
Out[127]: (-102.01000000000001, array([  8.,  10.]))
```

It can't turn this tuple into a valid 1d array, hence the error message.

Note that the arguments to your function are:

```
In [128]: ((x0[:numinputs],) + args)
Out[128]: (array([  1, 500]), 1, [8, 10])
```

`fsolve` passes the whole `args` tuple to your function.  It does not iterate through arrays or lists.

So you want `fsolve` for various `G` values, you have to do the iteration yourself.  `fsolve` (and most of the other `scipy` functions) won't do it for you.